# Unable to Use Live Update for Joomla! 3.6.1 (403 Access Forbidden)

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, access, one-click-updates

I was able to successfully update a site from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0 using the Live Update. However, when I attempted to update the same site to 3.6.1 a few minutes later, I was given a page stating:

> **An error has occurred.**

```
403 Access forbidden.
```

What can I do to get the latest update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Components > Joomla! Update.
2. On the "Live Update" tab, click the link to the update file to download it locally.
3. Click the "Upload & Update" tab.
4. Click the "Browse" button to navigate to the file you just downloaded.
5. Click the "Upload & Install" button.
6. Click "Clear Cache".
7. Navigate back to Components > Joomla! Update to ensure you get a **No updates available** message.

---

Note: If you are using Akeeba Backup, make sure you don't have the "System - Backup on update" plugin enabled before proceeding with the update.